# Alphabetizing an array of a data structure with reverse bubblesort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort an array of a 2 element data structure alphabetically. The whole program reads a data file into an array, then alphabetizes the array and searches it by query.

My problem is that after sorting the first entry of the database is cleared. This can be seen in the output at the end of this post.

Code follows

```
#include <iostream>                 //Required if your program does any I/O
#include <fstream>                  //Required for file I/O
#include <string>                   //Required if your program uses C++ strings

using namespace std;                //Required for ANSI C++ 1998 standard.

struct Book     // Data structure of database entry
{
       string title;
       string author;
};

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;      //Maximum database size
Book books [ARRAY_SIZE];          //Library database

void loadData ( int& librarySize ); //Function prototype to load data file into database
void showAll ( int librarySize );  //Function prototype to display entire database contents
void menu ( int librarySize ); //Function prototype to process menu of database functions
void searchByAuthor ( int librarySize );  //Function prototype to search database by author
void searchByTitle ( int librarySize );   //Function prototype to search database by title
void sortByAuthor ( int librarySize );    //Function prototype to alphabetically sort database by author
void sortByTitle ( int librarySize );     //Function prototype to alphabetically sort database by title

int main ()
{ 
    int librarySize = 0;           //Declaring and initializing databse size variable

    cout << "Welcome to Greathouse's Library Database" << endl;

    loadData ( librarySize );        //Prompt for and loading of data file into database.

    menu ( librarySize );  //Processing of database functions menu

    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}

void loadData ( int& librarySize )
{
    ifstream inputFile;         //File I/O variable
    string inputFileName;       //Data file path

    //Prompt for data file path
    cout << "Please enter the name of the backup file: ";
    getline(cin, inputFileName);

    // Open the data file.
    inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());      // Need .c_str() to convert a C++ string to a C-style string

    // Check the file opened successfully.
    if ( ! inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //Read data file into database
    for ( librarySize = 0; inputFile.peek() != EOF && librarySize < ARRAY_SIZE ; librarySize++ )
    {
        getline( inputFile, books[librarySize].title );
        getline( inputFile, books[librarySize].author );
    }

    //Confirm number of records loaded with user
    cout << librarySize << " records loaded successfully." << endl;

    // Clear EOF flag on file stream
    inputFile.clear();

    // Return to the beginning of the file stream
    inputFile.seekg(0);
}

void menu ( int librarySize )
{
     char command = ' ';

     //Display and processing of menu and commands until escape character 'q' is entered
     while ( command != 'Q' && command != 'q' )
     {
           cout << "Would you like to (Q)uit, (S)howall, Search by (A)uthor, or Search by (T)itle? : ";
           cin >> command;

           switch ( command )
           {
                  case 'S':
                  case 's':

                      showAll ( librarySize );           //Call to function to show database contents in response to user input
                      break;

                 case 'A':
                 case 'a':

                      searchByAuthor ( librarySize );    //Call to function to search database by author and display results alphabetically in response to user input

                      break;

                 case 'T':
                 case 't':

                      searchByTitle ( librarySize );     //Call to function to search database by title and display results alphabetically in response to user input

                      break;

                 case 'Q':
                 case 'q':

                      break;        //Case option to prevent extraneous output when quitting program

                 default:

                         cout << "That is not a valid command." << endl;
                         break;
          }
    }
}

void searchByAuthor ( int librarySize )   //Function to search database by author
{
     string authorSearch = " ";       //User query
     int authorResults = 0;  //Number of query results found
     int iteration = 0;  //Loop counting variable

     //Prompt for and reading of user query
     cout << "Author: : ";
     cin >> authorSearch;

     sortByAuthor ( librarySize ); //Call to sort database alphabetically by author so output will be alphabetical

     //Iterative search of database for all instances of query
     for ( iteration = 0; iteration <= librarySize; iteration++ )
     {
         if ( books[iteration].author.find ( authorSearch ) != string::npos )
         {
            cout << books[iteration].title << " (" << books[iteration].author << ")" << endl;
            authorResults++;
         }
     }

     cout << authorResults << " records found." << endl;                      //Output of number of results
}

void searchByTitle ( int librarySize )
{
     string titleSearch = " ";       //User query
     int titleResults = 0;  //Number of query results found
     int iteration = 0; //Loop counting variable

     //Prompt for and reading of user query
     cout << "Title: ";
     cin >> titleSearch;

     sortByTitle ( librarySize );     //Call to sort database alphabetically by title so output will be alphabetical

     //Iterative search of database for all instances of query
     for ( iteration = 0; iteration <= librarySize; iteration++ )
     {
         if ( books[iteration].title.find ( titleSearch ) != string::npos )
         {
            cout << books[iteration].title << " (" << books[iteration].author << ")" << endl;
            titleResults++;
         }                         
     }

     cout << titleResults << " records found." << endl;                       //Output of number of results
}

void showAll ( int librarySize )       //Function to show database contents
{
     //Iterative walk through database to display contents
     for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < librarySize; iteration++ )
     {
         cout << books[iteration].title << " (" << books[iteration].author << ")" << endl;
     }
}

void sortByAuthor ( int librarySize ) //Function to sort database alphabetically by author
{
     //Bubble sort of databse alphabetically by author
     for ( int pass = 0; pass < librarySize ; pass++ )
     {
         for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < librarySize - pass; iteration++ )
         {             
             if ( books[iteration].author > books[iteration+1].author )
             {
                  swap ( books[iteration] , books[iteration+1] );
             }
         }
     }
}

void sortByTitle ( int librarySize )      //Function to sort database alphabetically by title
{
     //Bubble sort of databse alphabetically by title
     for ( int pass = 0; pass < librarySize ; pass++ )
     {
         for ( int iteration = 0; iteration < librarySize - pass; iteration++ )
         {             
             if ( books[iteration].title > books[iteration+1].title )
             {
                  swap ( books[iteration] , books[iteration+1] );
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Test Data is

```
Objects First with Java  
Barnes and Kolling  
Game Development Essentials  
Novak  
The Game Maker's Apprentice  
Overmars  
C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis...  
Malik  
C++ Programming Lab Manual  
Scholl  
Beginning LINUX Programming  
Stones and Matthew  
C++ Programming: Program Design Including...  
D. S. Malik  
C++ How to Program  
Deitel and Deitel  
Programming and Problem Solving with C++  
Dale, Weems, Headington  
Game Character Development with Maya  
Ward  
Developing Games in Java  
Brackeen  
C# Programming  
Harvey, Robinson, Templeman, Watson  
Java Programming  
Farrell  
Audio for Games  
Brandon
```

Error output is

```
Welcome to Greathouse's Library Database
Please enter the name of the backup file: library.txt
14 records loaded successfully.
Would you like to (Q)uit, (S)howall, Search by (A)uthor, or Search by (T)itle? :
 s
Objects First with Java (Barnes and Kolling)
Game Development Essentials (Novak)
The Game Maker's Apprentice (Overmars)
C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis... (Malik)
C++ Programming Lab Manual (Scholl)
Beginning LINUX Programming (Stones and Matthew)
C++ Programming: Program Design Including... (D. S. Malik)
C++ How to Program (Deitel and Deitel)
Programming and Problem Solving with C++ (Dale, Weems, Headington)
Game Character Development with Maya (Ward)
Developing Games in Java (Brackeen)
C# Programming (Harvey, Robinson, Templeman, Watson)
Java Programming (Farrell)
Audio for Games (Brandon)
Would you like to (Q)uit, (S)howall, Search by (A)uthor, or Search by (T)itle? :
 t
Title: Game
Audio for Games (Brandon)
Developing Games in Java (Brackeen)
Game Character Development with Maya (Ward)
Game Development Essentials (Novak)
The Game Maker's Apprentice (Overmars)
5 records found.
Would you like to (Q)uit, (S)howall, Search by (A)uthor, or Search by (T)itle? :
 s
 ()
Audio for Games (Brandon)
Beginning LINUX Programming (Stones and Matthew)
C# Programming (Harvey, Robinson, Templeman, Watson)
C++ How to Program (Deitel and Deitel)
C++ Programming Lab Manual (Scholl)
C++ Programming: From Problem Analysis... (Malik)
C++ Programming: Program Design Including... (D. S. Malik)
Developing Games in Java (Brackeen)
Game Character Development with Maya (Ward)
Game Development Essentials (Novak)
Java Programming (Farrell)
Objects First with Java (Barnes and Kolling)
Programming and Problem Solving with C++ (Dale, Weems, Headington)
Would you like to (Q)uit, (S)howall, Search by (A)uthor, or Search by (T)itle? :
```

Comment: And you're not using `std::sort` because... ?

Comment: @Fred Larson: Because it's most likely homework.

Comment: @casablanca: Yeah, that's my guess too. Why else would you use bubble sort?

Comment: Is "Audio for Games" the one it's not finding?

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't need to sort by title to search by title. Sorting by title sorts by the first word, but you're checking the entire title. Your sort there just makes your search take longer without adding any benefit or optimization.

Comment: It's not finding the record for "The Game Maker's Apprentice
Overmars"

Comment: I know I don't have to sort to search, but the output is supposed to be alphabetized by sorting the array.

Comment: I've only used bubble sort twice in my professional life, and both times I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of your loops, you use this condition:

```
iteration <= librarySize
```

Your array indices range from `0` to `librarySize - 1` (since these are the indices populated by `loadData`), so the last valid entry in your array is `books[librarySize - 1]`. Try changing the loop condition to:

```
iteration < librarySize
```

**Edit:** There's also another problem in your sort function: you're trying to access `books[iteration+1]` which will once again be out of bounds during the first pass. Your inner loop should only go up to `librarySize - pass - 1`:

```
iteration < librarySize - pass - 1
```

Comment: True, but librarySize is not the size of the array, instead it is a value generated in the loadData function for the number of records read into the array.

Comment: @cyotee: I just corrected my answer -- the problem remains, because `loadData` only loads entries upto `librarySize - 1`. The last iteration inside `loadData` increments `librarySize` but immediately terminates, so that specific index is never populated.

Comment: The loadData function starts at array position 0, and reads two lines of the of the input file into the structure at each array position, then moves to the next position. Until it reaches the EOF of the data file, or 1000 records. The function reads all the entires in the data file, and does show them correctly before sorting.

Comment: @cyotee: Take an example where you read in 100 records; `librarySize` would be 100 but the valid entries are from `books[0]` to `books[99]`. There's a second similar error in your sort function (see my edited answer). Your program may appear to show the entries correctly since `std::string` is empty by default, but the problem remains.

Comment: @cyotee: You should also correct it to `librarySize - pass - 1` in your sort function -- that's why you're getting an empty entry when you do `showAll`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where your "bubble" is happening.  In both loops you start at array pos 0, you need to move up as each first element is in the correct place.  The end never gets sorted.

Here is some code that I have not tested so it could be off by 1 etc.  But you get the idea

```
 for ( int pass = 0; pass <= librarySize ; pass++ )
 {
     for ( int iteration = 0; iteration <= librarySize - pass; iteration++ )
     {             
         if ( books[iteration+pass].title > books[iteration+pass+1].title )
         {
              swap ( books[iteration+pass] , books[iteration+pass+1] );
         }
     }
 }
```

Or you could do it like this

```
 for ( int pass = 0; pass <= librarySize ; pass++ )
 {
     for ( int iteration = pass; iteration <= librarySize ; iteration++ )
     {             
         if ( books[iteration].title > books[iteration+1].title )
         {
              swap ( books[iteration] , books[iteration+1] );
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: As you can see, the second code block does not resolve the issue. But thank you, the manipulation should help track it down.

Comment: They altered the output by shifting the error further down into the output. Not sure what that means, but it might help.

Comment: @cyotee can you explain what the error looks like.  Are you sure your input data is correct?